# /proc/diskstats с хост-машины — в контейнер

Tags: linux, openvz

Как можно прокинуть `/proc/diskstats` в контейнер без монитрования `/proc` с родительского хоста?

Comment: кстати, а монтирование только одного этого файла не подойдёт?

Comment: на сколько я знаю файл нельзя смонтировать, только папку

Comment: да, вы правы. а с поиском/заменой строк ничего не вышло?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**обновление**

после дискуссий в комментариях выяснилось, что требуется подмена псевдо-файла `/proc/diskstats` в виртуальной файловой системе `proc`.

без пересборки программы *linux* это, насколько мне известно, невозможно.

но есть простое обходное решение **глобальной** задачи — замена в бинарном файле, от которого нет исходников, который и обращается к `/proc/diskstats`, строки `/proc/diskstats` на другую строку **ровно** такой же длины.

пример замены на строку `/tmp/diskstats1`:

```
sed s,/proc/diskstats,/tmp/diskstats1,g исходный.файл > исправленный.файл
```

---

**информация, неактульная для решения глобальной задачи, но, возможно полезная для иной ситуации**:

если есть возможность взаимодействовать через *tcp-порт*, то можно воспользоваться возможностями программы *netcat*:

на машине, которая будет предоставлять информацию, запускаем:

```
$ cat /proc/diskstats | nc -l 192.168.0.1 4444
```

программа `nc` будет ожидать подключений по адресу 192.168.0.1, на порту 4444 (цифры — только для примера).

а теперь с другой машины обратимся по этому адресу:

```
$ nc 192.168.0.1 4444
8       0 sda 1599242 1780282 30228610 ...
...
```

т.е., на другой машине мы получили то, что *linux* первой машины выдаёт в псевдо-файл `/proc/diskstats`.

если запрашивать информацию надо неоднократно, то первую команду можно «обернуть» в бесконечный цикл (`nc` завершится сразу же после передачи данных по сети). например, так:

```
$ while true; do cat /proc/diskstats | nc -l 192.168.0.1 4444; done
```

Comment: Идея классная, но программа в контейнере бинарная (исходников нет).

Comment: @al7, и в ней «зашито намертво» обращение к `/proc/diskstats`? если она не шифрованная/упакованная, то, скорее всего, эту строку в ней можно найти и заменить на путь к другому файлу. посмотреть строки в файле: `strings файл | grep diskstats`.

Comment: `strings` строку находит. Заменит через текстовый редактор, получаю ошибку сегментации. Если что делаю не правильно, прошу поправить.

Comment: *Заменит через текстовый редактор... , получаю ошибку сегментации* — если это бинарный файл, то так и должно быть. текстовые редакторы — для редактирования текста. воспользуйтесь `sed`-ом каким-нибудь. примерно так: `sed s,/proc/diskstats,/tmp/diskstats1,g исходный.файл > исправленный.файл`. только длину замены (я для примера написал `/tmp/diskstats1`) подгоните **ровно** под длину заменяемой строки (`/proc/diskstats`), иначе тоже будет *segfault*.

Comment: Работает, спасибо за помощь